# SQL Server Query to find records with aggregate funct on one column but multiple columns in select clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, having-clause

Here is the minimized version of the Customer table. There can be customers having same account number mapped to different Group . I am looking to find out customer numbers which are mapped to more than one group. As I was using sybase my query below was working fine. Same query does not work in SQL Server.

Can I get both custAccnt and corresponding custId in one query as below.

```
select DISTINCT lt.custAccnt, lt.custId from VAL_CUSTOMERS lt 
where lt.eligible = 'Y' group by lt.custAccnt 
having count(distinct lt.custId) > 1

+----------+-----------+---------+----------+
| custName | custAccnt | custId  | eligible |
+----------+-----------+---------+----------+
| Joe      | AB1VU1235 |   43553 | Y        |
| Joe      | AB1VU1235 |  525577 | Y        |
| Lucy     | CDNMY4568 |  332875 | Y        |
| Lucy     | CDNMY4568 |  211574 | Y        |
| Lucy     | CDNMY4568 |  211345 | Y        |
| Manie    | TZMM7S009 |  123890 | Y        |
| Tom      | YFDU1235  | 1928347 | Y        |
| Tom      | YFDU1235  |  204183 | Y        |
| Chef     | TNOTE6573 |  734265 | Y        |
+----------+-----------+---------+----------+
```

Result :-

```
+-----------+---------+
| AB1VU1235 |   43553 |
| AB1VU1235 |  525577 |
| CDNMY4568 |  332875 |
| CDNMY4568 |  211574 |
| CDNMY4568 |  211345 |
| YFDU1235  | 1928347 |
| YFDU1235  |  204183 |
+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT combined with GROUP BY... Usually a bad sign...

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work...

"...customer numbers which are mapped to more than one group..." ,  <-- `group` is `custAcct`?

```
select t.custAccnt, t.custId 
from VAL_CUSTOMERS t 
where (Select count(distinct custAccnt ) 
       from VAL_CUSTOMERS 
       Where custId = t.custId) > 1
```

The statement "...customer numbers which are mapped to more than one group..." does not say anything about "eligibility", so I did not mention it.  If you really meant to say:

"...*eligible* customer numbers which are mapped to more than one group...", then try this:

```
select t.custAccnt, t.custId 
from VAL_CUSTOMERS t 
where eligible = 'Y'
  and (Select count(distinct custAccnt ) 
       from VAL_CUSTOMERS 
       Where custId = t.custId) > 1
```

or, this might be faster... it answers a slightly different, but, (I think) equivalent question,
"find ...*eligible* customer numbers where there is another row for the same customer number mapped to a different custAccnt ..."

```
select t.custAccnt, t.custId 
from VAL_CUSTOMERS t 
where eligible = 'Y'
  and exists 
      (Select * from VAL_CUSTOMERS 
       Where custId = t.custId
         and custAccnt != t.custAccnt )
```

Comment: Sorry. It does not work. Could you tell me why you tried for count(distinct custAccnt) >1

Comment: Because you said " customer numbers which are mapped to more than one group " and a "group" is defined by CustAcct, no ?  You don't say, explicitly, but *your* query attempt groups by custAccnt ...   So what does this query do?

Comment: group --> custId.. I got your point and updates the query. It looks correct. But its taking long long time even if index created on columns.

Comment: Try the second alternative SQL query and see if it is any faster.  Otherwise, without extensive information about the database schema, the data in the database and indices on it, I cannot help further.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to tackle this. Here are a couple of them that should work.

```
select lt.custAccnt
    , lt.custId 
from VAL_CUSTOMERS lt 
cross apply
(
    select c.custAccnt
    from VAL_CUSTOMERS c
    where c.custAccnt = lt.custAccnt
    group by c.custAccnt
    having count(*) > 1
) x
where lt.eligible = 'Y'


select lt.custAccnt
    , lt.custId 
from VAL_CUSTOMERS lt 
where lt.eligible = 'Y'
AND lt.custAccnt IN
(
    select c.custAccnt
    from VAL_CUSTOMERS c
    group by c.custAccnt
    having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Sorry. It does not work. The internal query returning custAccnt which is present multiple times. I am looking for  custAccnt with multiple custId

Comment: Can you explain how this doesn't work? Both of these queries produce EXACTLY the output you stated you are looking for. http://rextester.com/VIRUY88590

Answer (score 0):

In case of duplicates custAccnt and custId in the table, @Sean query won't work.

```
WITH cte AS(SELECT *
                 , COUNT (custId) OVER (PARTITION BY custAccnt) AS CntcustId
                 , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY custAccnt, custId ORDER BY custName)    AS Rownum
                 FROM VAL_CUSTOMERS
                 WHERE eligible = 'Y'
)
SELECT custAccnt, custId
FROM cte
WHERE CntcustId>1
AND Rownum = 1;
```

Using row number to eliminate the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte1
( custName , custAccnt , custId  , eligible )
As
(

 SELECT 'Joe'      ,'AB1VU1235' ,   43553 , 'Y'    UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Joe'      ,'AB1VU1235' ,  525577 , 'Y'    UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Lucy'     ,'CDNMY4568' ,  332875 , 'Y'    UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Lucy'     ,'CDNMY4568' ,  211574 , 'Y'    UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Lucy'     , 'CDNMY4568' ,  211345 , 'Y'   UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Manie'    ,'TZMM7S009' ,  123890 , 'Y'    UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Tom'      ,'YFDU1235'  , 1928347 , 'Y'    UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Tom'      ,'YFDU1235'  ,  204183 , 'Y'    UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Chef'     ,'TNOTE6573' ,  734265 , 'Y'    
  )

,cte2 AS (
    SELECT custName
          ,custAccnt
          ,count(custName) cnt
    FROM cte1
    GROUP BY custName,custAccnt
    )
,cte3 AS (
    SELECT custName
        ,cnt
    FROM cte2 WHERE cnt <> 1
         )

SELECT custAccnt
    ,custId
FROM cte1
WHERE custName IN (
        SELECT custName
        FROM cte3
        )
```